# How to bind strings with f11 key in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to bind strings with  f11 key in vim.
Here is the target strings.

`<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: true --` `>`

```
 <!-- language: lang-html -->
 <!-- language: lang-css -->  
 <!-- end snippet -->
```

When to press f11 in insert mode ,the strings will be written into my editing file in vim.

How to write the map in .vimrc?

Comment: Please improve and **edit your question** **to *avoid* images**, and put your strings there as code with four spaces before each line.

Comment: I want to paste the string instead of image here,but strings with four spaces like formatted codes ,can't display properly.

Comment: You could then use backquotes like this: `<!-- language: foo -->`. No need to past any image. I'm actually surprised that with such a low score you are allowed to past images.

Comment: You did not try hard enough to edit your question. I was able to put some of the strings. Please **edit again your question** to improve it. The code lines (starting with four spaces) should be in a new (paragraph-like) block

Comment: Can you put all lines?Please show me how.

Comment: No, please do it yourself. I voted to close your question, will unvote when it is properly formatted (*without* any images). Your question should have no images at all.

Comment: done,&lt; and &lt; do.

Comment: Did you read some [vim book](http://www.oualline.com/vim-book.html)? It has several chapters about your question. Did you consider switching to `emacs`, where doing that is (IMHO) much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a file with the content you want to insert
- Using the `:r filename` [command](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_a_file) you can insert it
- You can [bind](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)) this to F11 in your vimrc: `map <F11> :r filename<CR>`